# Meta Title Breaking After Apostrophe

Tags: templates, html, title, metadata, meta

EE 5.2.2

The title meta tag from the default site html-wrapper template is this `<meta property="og:title" content="{layout:og_title}">`. It is working great for everything except if there's an apostrophe in the title, in which case the output stops before the apostrophe. So the title `Love Doesn't Stop` is rendered as `Love Doesn`.

I've tried other options such as using conditionals to pull the `{title}` from the channel entry itself, which, when I view the page source, renders `Love Doesn&#8217;t Stop` but still uses `Love Doesn` when linking out.

I have also tried changing the actual title from `Love Doesn't Stop` to `Love Doesn&#8217;t Stop`, but the same thing still happens: I end up with `Love Doesn`.

Is this an EE problem or an HTML problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the attr_safe modifier on your tag (where the value is generated, not the layout tag) - https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/variable-modifiers.html#attr_safe - that will convert special characters to HTML entities which should work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did what you suggested. The result was the apostrophe rendered as an HTML entity when I inspect it but it still cut off in the title when the link gets posted. I'm not sure how to proceed with this one.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I also have a similar issue with Channel names where I have to include the unicode character, or the name will be truncated in the layout tag. (But then I still end up with html characters in the title tag).

attr_safe doesn't seem to work consistently and I haven't had any luck trying to use its unicode_punctuation= parameter either.

Did you find anything that worked for you?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I ended up having to go a different rout.